# VBscript code replacement solution on listing files in local directories

Tags: javascript, jquery, vbscript

Looking for a non-vb solution to collect file names in local directories and put in a javascript array. The app is not web bound. It will only be run locally. The vb solution is below. Currently this works fine but I need to go another route on the file name collection. After the script below runs I have some javascript that picks up the vars- wood, metal, plastic- and runs with them. Any suggestions on another script solution to getting a local directory of file names that will run in firefox or chrome? I'm not running a local webserver but have considered nodejs-seems a bit overkill for what I need. This is a local webbrowser application using html,css,javascript,and jquery.

```
  <script language="vbscript">
 'List Files in a particular Directory
 Dim fs2, f2, fs3, f3, fs4, f4, wood, metal, plastic, folderspec2, folderspec3, folderspec4, strFileName2

  folderspec2 = ".\wood"
folderspec3 = ".\metal"
folderspec4 = ".\plastic"

Set fs2 = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 Set f2 = fs2.GetFolder(folderspec2)

For Each FileName In f2.files
 wood = wood & fileName.name
 wood = wood & ","
 Next
   set f2 = nothing
 set fs2 = nothing

Set fs3 = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 Set f3 = fs3.GetFolder(folderspec2)

For Each FileName In f3.files
 metal = metal & fileName.name
 metal = metal & ","
 Next

  set f3 = nothing
 set fs3 = nothing

Set fs4 = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 Set f4 = fs4.GetFolder(folderspec2)

For Each FileName In f4.files
 plastic = plastic & fileName.name
 plastic = plastic & ","
 Next

  set f4 = nothing
 set fs4 = nothing

 </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it in the browser. Providing a sandbox with protections from things like access to the file system is core feature of what web browsers do. Without that security feature the web would not be a viable platform. There is no way around this short of making users install a plugin to the browser.

Since this will only run on one machine, what I recommend is that you write a background service to run on the computer in the general purpose language of your choice that, on a schedule, reads the list of files from the folders you want on the file system and writes them into a javascript array in a special file on the computer that your web browser/html page will be able to read and use.

Comment: Thank you for the reply and suggestion. I was looking for a more portable solution but may be forced into the cataclysmic decision of being OS specific with perhaps a reboot trigger to fire the code. I could work with a plugin since this is a closed app but it would need to work on firefox or chrome. I understand the browser security dilemma but thought I would reach out at least once before I start down the other road.